# Archaic vs Historical in dictionaries

Tags: differences, terminology

At Oxford Dictionaries Online the word [alderman](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/alderman?q=alderman) is marked as "chiefly historical", whereas [ere](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ere?q=ere) is marked as "literary or archaic".

I've looked around on the ODO site, but I can't find a guide to explain the difference. To me they both mean "old and not really used any more".

How does *archaic* differ from *historical* in word definitions?

Comment: So is that saying that *literary* and *archaic* are the same thing, or that they are two different possible things?

Comment: I think that *literary* indicates something different to *archaic*. I could be wrong.

Comment: I would understand _archaic_ as a synonym to pre-historic. So a use marked as _historic_ is more recent than a use marked _archaic_.

Comment: Just a guess, and maybe I'm stating the obvious, but I would think words chiefly found in poetry (such as e'er, 'twas, e'en) would be designated as _literary_ in the same way that [other dictionaries](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/e%27en?rdfrom=E%27en) might use the designation _poetic_. The ODO defines [_e'en_](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/e%27en?q=e%27en) as "literary form of EVEN".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An archaic word is one that is no longer in everyday use but sometimes used to impart an old-fashioned flavour, while a historical word is one used to describe a thing of the past. On the other hand, a literary word is one that is connected to literature. As can be seen, these three mean slightly different things.

Comment: Hm, and *literary*?  Is it one or the other of *archaic* or *historical*, or both or neither?

Comment: Indeed they do. But only just.

Comment: No, they [certainly do exist](http://www.cityofchicago.org/city/en/about/council.html), and not only just.

Comment: As supporting evidence, see this article from Merriam-Webster about this topic, linked from a similar question: https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/whats-the-difference-between-archaic-and-obsolete

Answer (score 10):

I've had an email from the Oxford University Press, and this is what they say:

> Archaic: very old-fashioned language, not in ordinary use at all today, but sometimes used to give a deliberately old-fashioned effect or found in works of the past that are still widely read.
>
> Historical: still used today, but only to refer to some practice or artefact that is no longer part of the modern world, i.e. baldric or almoner.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the OED definitions of those two words –

> archaic, adj.
>
> a. Marked by the characteristics of an earlier period; old-fashioned, primitive, antiquated. spec. in Archaeol., designating an early or formative period of artistic style or culture.
>
> b. esp. of language: Belonging to an earlier period, no longer in common use, though still retained either by individuals, or generally, for special purposes, poetical, liturgical, etc. Thus the pronunciation obleege is archaic in the first case; the pronoun thou in the second.
>
> historical, adj. and n.
>
> 1 A (a) Belonging to, constituting, or of the nature of history; in accordance with history.
>
> 1 A (b) spec. Belonging to or of the nature of history as opposed to fiction or legend.