# Google Oxford dictionary word differences

Tags: dictionaries

I want to know on what basis do dictionaries place certain equivalent words into separate sections. Below is an example when performing a Google search (which uses Oxford dictionary) for the word *fly*. Notice how the result puts the word into separate sections with superscripts 1, 2 and 3.  Trying to find out what are typically the differences between these sections and if there is a standard convention.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hint: Look at the part-of-speech labels.

Comment: The people at Lexico consider these to be different words: note the different etymologies (or apology) given.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking about a compilation decision made by one particular dictionary panel. This information should be available in the electronic preface or (and especially if it is unclear how their decisions lead to the strange partitioning seen in this example) by contacting the editorial board.

Comment: I have emailed OUP in the past and received a reply. ([see here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/103896/3559)) You could try that. Lexico has a "[contact us](https://www.lexico.com/contact-us)" page.

Comment: They are different words with different etymologies.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This is just an example. This type of organization is common to most dictionaries.

Comment: @Barmar I’m voting to close this question because it is asking about a compilation decision made by particular dictionary panels. This information should be available in the electronic prefaces or (and especially if it is unclear how their decisions lead to the strange partitioning seen in this example) by contacting the relevant editorial boards.

Comment: [AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fly) clearly distinguishes homonyms from polysemes, giving three separate (though all related!) etymologies for the three different words _fly_ it decides there are.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think that is the answer: different dictionaries use different ways to organize the definitions.

Comment: @jimm101 The question is off-topic; earlier questions about how individual dictionaries (rather than the language itself) work have been closed. But since Lexico does include 3 etymologies for its 3 purported homonyms (one admittedly sketchy), I'm wondering whether the above is misquoted.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth does the edit fix this?

Answer (score 1):

When you're translating from another language or you don't understand a new word, you often want the one meaning of the word that will explain and fit in with the context.

The naive understanding of words is that one word has one meaning and one meaning has one word for it (like we expect math and science to do).

But that is just not the case. One word (a sound sequence in speech or a sequence of letters in spelling) can  have other meanings depending on context (the surrounding words or the real world context).

A good dictionary will give different entries with context specific examples, either made-up or actually found in literature. **These different entries are for *distinct* meanings**. The difference could be part of speech (whether a word is used as a noun or as a verb gives a change of some aspect of meaning), or it could be a metaphorical use, or it could be for etymologically different sources that somehow phonologically converged, or many other possible reasons.

In your example 'fly', the canonical meaning is of a certain small insect. But if you're reading or hearing something about baseball, it's most likely referring to a 'pop fly', a ball hit in a high arc. That is not at all the same thing as an insect. (it is most likely semantically related since both go in the air somehow).

A dictionary attempts to give these different meanings in different entries.

Comment: The _noun_ means a kind of insect; the _verb_ has various meanings to do with travelling through the air; there is also an informal use as an _adjective_.

Comment: This is the right core answer, though it seems to me that the OP is clear on why verb and noun uses are given separately. I took it they were asking why there are 5 entries in the verb section. Maybe edit the example to compare two different verb uses?

Comment: @AndyBonner: OP is asking about *fly* [superscript 1], *fly* [superscript 2], and *fly* [superscript 3].

Comment: @TinfoilHat Hmm.... I suppose that's clear enough from the fact that they posted all the screenshots. I had actually been assuming that "superscript" was being misused for the ordered list of the definitions. I still think it would be helpful (to the OP, as well as future visitors) to highlight the distinction between meanings within a part of speech.

Comment: I'm getting the feeling that my answer is to a somewhat different question than the OP really has. The OP is asking about the content under each numbered superscript but doesn't say exactly why. I think the difficulty is that there is a lot of overlap - superscript 1 has verb and noun definitions (the latter lacking the animal, 2 has the noun just for that animal, 3 adjective but very slangy. To be frank, the answer  is only available by asking Google and  their dictionary search UI team. We can only speculate - it's not particularly standard. I can't tell what the pattern is.

Comment: Google has changed their source dictionaries over time. As of this moment the text/layout in the OP image is identical to that from [lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fly).

Comment: Exploring, I've found Oxford University Press's [description of their format](https://languages.oup.com/about-us/what-is-a-dictionary-dataset/) which unfortunately has everything -but- the meaning of the superscript.